# Loop through properties and set the value of each property as an item in a list, print the list and then set the value again? C#

Tags: c#, html

I currently have this loop:

```
 if (lists.Date.Count() == 0)
        {
            message = "There Have Been No Merged Pull Requests In This Repository";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Date.Count(); i++)
            PullRequests = new List<PullRequestDetails>
            
        {
                new PullRequestDetails()
                { 
                    Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[i],
                    Name = lists.Name[i],
                    Date = lists.Date[i],
                    CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[i],

            },   
        };
        }
```

which takes strings from lists and sets them in this model:

```
 public class PullRequestDetails
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Date { get; set; }
    public string? CommitLink { get; set; }
}
```

I want my HTML to display every item from the list when the button is clicked, but currently it is only displaying the last item from the list:

```
@if (Model.PullRequests != null)
            {
                @foreach (var requests in Model.PullRequests)
                {
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@requests.Title</td>
                            <td>@requests.Name</td>
                            <td>@requests.Date</td>
                            <td><a href=@requests.CommitLink target="_blank"> Link </a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                }
            }
```

This works when I manually add each value of the list, but his gives an out of range exception when there are less or more than 4 values in each list (which there are in most cases):

```
        if (lists.Date.Count() == 0)
        {
            html = "There Have Been No Merged Pull Requests In This Repository";

        }
        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Date.Count(); i++)
            PullRequests = new List<PullRequestDetails>
            
        {
                new PullRequestDetails()
                {
                    
                    Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[0],
                    Name = lists.Name[0],
                    Date = lists.Date[0],
                    CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[0]
            },
            new PullRequestDetails()
                {

                    Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[1],
                    Name = lists.Name[1],
                    Date = lists.Date[1],
                    CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[1]
            },
            new PullRequestDetails()
                {

                    Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[2],
                    Name = lists.Name[2],
                    Date = lists.Date[2],
                    CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[2]
            },
            new PullRequestDetails()
                {

                    Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[3],
                    Name = lists.Name[3],
                    Date = lists.Date[3],
                    CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[3]
            },

        };
        }
```

So how can I fix this with a loop?

Comment: you create a new list on every iteration.

Comment: In the first piece of code, you override `PullRequests` with each iteration of the loop. You need to instantiate `PullRequests` outside the loop and just add the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Camilo Terevinto said you need too take the List instantiation out of the loop

```
    if (lists.Date.Count() == 0)
    {
        message = "There Have Been No Merged Pull Requests In This Repository";
    }
    else
    {
        PullRequests = new List<PullRequestDetails>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Date.Count(); i++)
        {
            PullRequests.Add(new PullRequestDetails()
            { 
                Title = lists.ShortRequestTitle[i],
                Name = lists.Name[i],
                Date = lists.Date[i],
                CommitLink = lists.ShortCommitList[i]
            });   
        };
    }
```